# Semisimples rings and units

Tags: ring-theory

Is possible to proof directly of definition of semiplicity this: if R is a semisimple ring, then R have unit?

Answer (score 1):

The reason semisimple (Artinian, associative) rings are rarely (never?) talked about is that the classification theorems break down. Certainly the Artin-Wedderburn theorem only deals with semisimple rings with identity.

An answer to your question depends on what you are calling "semisimple."

For example, if you're thinking of "all right ideals are summands" then already $2\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$ is such a ring without identity. It's also Artinian and simple, but it does not have radical zero.

If you are thinking of semisimple as "finite product of simple rings" then there is a class of examples: many semisimple Lie algebras which don't have identity.